# Как на странице отобразить данные, введённые на другой странице без использования сессий?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть основная страница, на которой пользователь выбирает дату и получает 3 ссылки на другие страницы. На 3х других страницах отображается информация в зависимости от даты.

Сейчас код выглядит примерно так:

```
class MainPageView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = MainForm(request.user, request.GET)
        if request.GET.get('submitted') and form.is_valid():
            request.session['date'] = form.cleaned_data['date']

        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "main.html", context)

class Page1View(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context ={'date': request.session['date']}
        return render(request, "page1.html", context)
```

Есть ли способ сделать что-то подобное без использования сессий?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, залить данные в Датабазу. А потом вылить их на второй сайт.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Кажется хранить в сессии только дату избыточно, попробуйте формировать url адрес страниц, вида **/page/2021-12-28**, тоесть urls.py, будет выглядеть примерно вот так

```
from django.urls import path
from some_app.views import Page1View

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^page/(?P<some_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$', Page1View.as_view(), name='my_date'),
]
```

views.py

```
class Page1View(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context ={'date': request.GET.get('some_date')}
        return render(request, "page1.html", context)
```

То есть основная идея, сформировать url, в котором записана некая дата, а затем её перехватывать в необходимой вьюхи, таким способом мы не используем сессии и подавно не записываем ненужную информации в БД.
Учтите, что я привел пример кода, который вероятно у вас не заработает, также вероятно, что перехваченную дату вам придётся сконвертировать.

Небольшой upd, приведу работающий пример передачи даты в view, в самой view также приводим конвертацию в объект date, что бы дальше было проще работать, с перехваченной датой.

Так выглядит urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

from app.views import Page1View

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^page/(?P<some_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/$',  Page1View.as_view(), name='my_date')
]
```

views.py

```
from datetime import datetime

from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views import View

class Page1View(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context ={'date': datetime.strptime(self.kwargs.get('some_date'), '%Y-%m-%d').date()}
        return render(request, "page1.html", context)
```